# Убрать горизонтальный скролл

Tags: css

помогите пожалуйста на [этой страничке](http://surma.pro/) убрать горизонтальный скролл

не пойму в чём дело. ширина .wrap 1073px , а ширина body почему то 1280px хотя никаким правилом не прописана

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем смотри в чем дело.

У тебя есть блок с надписью:[image]
<sub>(источник: [upyourpic.org](http://upyourpic.org/images/201303/esh58j3vv7.png))</sub>

Из-за неё как раз все беды, если убрать последний `cufon` элемент, то становится всё ок.

Решение:

- установить правильный размер `canvas` элемента внутри этого `cufon` элемента;
- вместо `canvas`'a просто вставить изображение и не париться;
- добавить тегу `body css` свойство `overflow-x:hidden`.